# Delete EFS encrypted file without certificate

Tags: windows-10, efs

I used to use a Yubikey with a certificate for file encryption. I then modified the encryption certificate on the key assuming I could use the backup certificate stored on a flash drive to decrypt the files. Unfortunately, Windows will only accept a smart card and not a certificate file on my computer, and so I cannot do anything to the file.

Is there a way to simply delete the file? I do not need it anymore and I'd prefer to not have it on my desktop all the time.  I already tried changing the encryption certificate to the one stored on my computer, but it won't let me open it either way.

When I attempt to delete the file I get the following prompt:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it should be more involved then just deleting the file and then emptying the recycle bin?

Comment: @Ramhound Because Windows says no when I try to simply delete the file, [like this](https://www.ducohosting.com/screenshots/iHTvRXyeiHTvRXye.png)

Comment: Booting into a live Linux environment would be your next option.  [Be sure you are using the backup certificate the correct way.](http://superuser.com/questions/942149/how-to-use-backup-efs-certificate-to-decrypt-encrypted-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), I ended up booting into a live Linux environment from a USB stick and deleted the file from there.